# Zoom on a imageView on android

Tags: android, image, layout

I am trying to implement a effect like the image below. I am able to do the rounded image and cropping for it. But what i have problems with is the zooming of the picture that is chosen as a profile picture.

Do you guys and girls have any tips how i could achieve this zoom-effect
 [image]

Also if you have any tips on how i could achieve the blur effect would be awesome.

Comment: https://github.com/tenthbitinc/ZoomImageView

Answer (score 0):

use this lib 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

```
ImageView mImageView;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

// Set the Drawable displayed
Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

// Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
 }


  // If you later call  ImageView.setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap/setImageResource/etc then you just need to call
 attacher.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.To achieve zooming you can just change the size of your bitmap programatically.

2.In order to get blur effect it is quite simple.Just increase your image size to lets say 10 times of its original size. then take the same image and then shrink it to your desired dimensions.The pic will pixellate and you will see a blur effect out there.